# Installation of Sonata ClassificationBundle autoload ClassNotFound

Tags: php, symfony, sonata, symfony-3.4

I'm try to install Sonata ClassificationBundle on my project in symfony 3.4.

But i can't install it correctly, i thinks i have missing something.

I have pass all step but my application display this message:

```
Attempted to load class "ApplicationSonataClassificationBundle" from namespace "Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle". 
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

I have try to add class to autoload with

```
"psr-4": {
   ...
   "Application\\Sonata\\ClassificationBundle": "src/Application/Sonata/ClassificationBundle",
   "Application\\": "/src/Application"
    },
```

Without result same error.

My class was perfectly generate.

[image: ApplicationSonataClassificationBundle]

How can i do ?

Thanks

[Sonata ClassificationBundle Documentation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/classification/2-x/doc/reference/installation.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no need for an extra PSR-4 entry.

`Application\\` -> `src/Application`

is enough, but you should remove the leading / before `src`.